# Unseen Theorem Based on parallelogram

Tags: geometry

In the figure, $ APQ= ABD$, $AB\parallel DC$ and $AD\parallel BC$ then prove that $RC=AP$[image]

My Attempt

While trying to show $\triangle ADP=\triangle RCB$
$$\angle DAP=\angle RCB$$
$$AD=BC$$

I was trying to show these triangles equal by congruency but couldn't get sufficient proof. Can anyone help me with this?

Note: it's NOT a compulsion to use congruency

Comment: When you say APQ = ABD, do you mean that the triangles are congruent and that AB = AQ and AD = AP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\triangle APQ= ABD\iff\triangle DOQ= POB$$

Adding $\triangle OBQ,$

$$\triangle PBQ= DBQ$$

$$\implies DP \parallel BQ\iff DP \parallel BR$$

$\implies\square DPBR$ is a parallelogram  $\implies DR=PB$

But $DC=DR+RC, AB=AP+PB$ as  $\square ABCD$ is a parallelogram

Comment: how did u get $ DOQ= POB$

Comment: @user335710, $O$ is the intersection of $PQ,DB$

Comment: how did u get, $DP||BQ$?

Comment: @user335710, See http://www.meritnation.com/ask-answer/question/prove-that-two-triangles-having-the-same-base-or-equal-base/math/3490230